# No tables are created after setting WillCascadeOnDelete on true

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, cascade

We are making a project in ASP MVC4, and are using code-first. This means that our database is automaticly created from our code after running it. But i noticed that optional relationships in the database dont have cascade on delete turned on by default.

So after googling, i found that you had to add it in your context, but this gives me errors.

**After I set WillCascadeOnDelete on true and delete my database so the Entity Framework can create it again, it creates the database with no tables in. But if i put it on false, it works without any problems.**

Here is the code i use to put it on true:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasOptional(r => r.PartOfLocations)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Here is my location model:

```
public class Location
{
    [Key, DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name"), Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.ClassModelStrings))]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public int LocationTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocationTypeId")]
    public virtual LocationType LocationType { get; set; }



    public virtual ICollection<Location> PartOfLocations { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

Also, if i delete the database to quick after it was created, it gives an error: The database XXX is not accessible.

And it adds " ( single user ) " after the database name, no idea if this helps

Comment: Just a side note: you are talking about **Entity Framework**. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC (although it's interesting to know that) and this is absolutely not about *asp-classic*. Also, it's not *ASP* who is creating your database, it's the **EF**.

Comment: If you have solved your problem then post an answer to your question with the solution; don't edit it into the question.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your title. Post the solution as an answer and then accept it. That marks the question as "solved".

Comment: OMG sorry, im completely new on this site, thanks again for correcting me.

Btw, i thought i found the answer but i didnt, so i still accept any possible solutions!

Comment: any errors ? Ot Just it did nothing ?   Un usual.  There are times when EF cant accept Cascade on delete due to complex relationships. eg 2 references to the same table.. incase you have a safari account: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449317867/4dot-using-convention-and-configuration-for-relationships/id2985218#X2ludGVybmFsX0J2ZGVwRmxhc2hSZWFkZXI/eG1saWQ9OTc4MTQ0OTMxNzg2Ny83OA==

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And no, i do not get any errors. It just creates no database.

Even though im not sure where to check for errors?